# Ubuntu cannot connect to LAN using USB Wi-Fi dongle

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm using a Totolink 11n USB Wi-Fi adapter on my laptop to connect to my LAN (the network card interface seems to be broken). My laptop has Ubuntu installed along with Windows 7 and I'm running into this problem:

On Windows, when trying to connect to the local network, if I check `Connect automatically` then I will not be able to connect to internet. If I uncheck that section, it works ok.

On Ubuntu, I cannot connect to internet even if I config a static IP address following [these](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/) instructions.

Could you tell me what `Connect automatically` is and possibly how to solve the Ubuntu connection problem in this case?

Comment: Connect automatically does exactly what it says on the tin. It stores any credentials for future authentication and, when the network is in range, your computer will automatically attempt to connect to the network so you don't have to.

Comment: What you might want to try in Windows is to remove all stored wifi networks, run (elevated) cmd -> `netsh winsock reset` -> reboot -> reconnect to your wifi.

Comment: Have you recently made any configuration changes in your router - such as changing the wifi password?

Comment: @BigChris Not at all, it's public wifi network and I can't change its configuration. For your first comment: I have the same thinking still I don't understand why with that simple change my laptop can connect to the network but, without that change, it failed to connect.

Comment: OK, but your question talks about your LAN - nothing about a public WiFi. Public WiFi networks you will require the DHCP client otherwise Ubuntu has no idea that it is being assigned an address automatically (DHCP).